# How do I center the contents in this div?

Tags: html, css

Here is a link: http://jsfiddle.net/zCXMv/18/

I can not figure out how to get this working. Please help.

HTML:

```
<div id="button" >
    <a class="button1 active" rel="1"></a>
    <a class="button2" rel="2"></a>
    <a class="button3" rel="3"></a>
    <a class="button4" rel="4"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button1,
.button2,
.button3,
.button4    {
    background:#999;
    padding:6px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}

#button {
    width: 50%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/zCXMv/19/

I made the buttons `display: inline-block`, removed the `float`s and added `text-align: center` to the parent.

```css
.button1,
.button2,
.button3,
.button4
{
    background:#999;
    padding:6px;
    display: inline-block; // Changed from "block"
    margin-right:5px;
    // Removed floats    
}

#button
{
    width: 50%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center; // Added central alignment to content
}
```

```html
<div id="button" >
    <a class="button1 active" rel="1"></a>
    <a class="button2" rel="2"></a>
    <a class="button3" rel="3"></a>
    <a class="button4" rel="4"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
.button1,
.button2,
.button3,
.button4    {
    background:#999;
    padding:6px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}

#button {
    width: 50%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#button a{
display:block;
 margin:auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "display: block" and "float:left" on the buttons, and add "text-align: center" to the #button definition.

Display "inline-block" is not supported in all browsers, so I would recommend not using this unless you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It may work:

```
#button a{display:block;margin:0 auto !important;text-align:center !important;}
```

Comment: Please, provide explaination for a better understanding. This block code is not sufficient to get the point (at least for begginers)